About the strange behavior of mailto:
I have included <a href="mailto:(MyEmailAddress)>contact me</a> link in my HTML file. It does serve the purpose of opening a blank Outlook instance ready for editing a reply email. However, it also opens my mailbox so that its contents are all exposed to the public. Is the latter a fault? And how to fix that.
Note:

Any user can email me so that verification of the user's identity is not necessary.
I don't have a backend account to receive the result of GET or POST.
Modification (in HTML and CSS only) is more preferable.


Your mailbox is not exposed to the public.

@Toto Why is that? When I test my HTML file by clicking the email link, both (the blank outlook and email-box) are opened. Maybe  you are talking about the highlighted word "exposed" is not that appropriate.

When clicking on mailto link, it opens the local mailer.

@Toto Glad to know that.

Nothing is wrong.

“However, it also opens my mailbox so that its contents are all exposed to the public.”

It opens your mailbox on your machine only. For another user it could open Apple Mail (macOS) or Thunderbird (alternative mail client) on their machine and it is no big deal.
Opening Outlook on your local machine is not a security risk; it is expected behavior.
The way it works is mailto is a protocol handler that tells the client web browser, “Hey! When this is clicked, open up your local mail client!” And then the added email after that can be any destination to email address at all; not just yours.
You can even set it to mailto:biden@whitehouse.gov and that will open up an email client with a new email window with the destination to email address set to biden@whitehouse.gov.
Here is info from MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) Web Docs specifically about mailto:; bold emphasis is mine:

It's fairly common to find web pages link to resources using non-http protocols. An example is the mailto: protocol:
<a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Web Master</a>

Web authors can use a mailto: link when they want to provide a convenient way for users to send an email, directly from the webpage. When the link is activated, the browser should launch the default desktop application for handling email. You can think of this as a desktop-based protocol handler.


Do you mean if the testing is done on my own machine, the mentioned events will happen. But If I run it from other machine, the latter event would not happen.?

That's exactly right. Think as the mailto: the same as any other url. It is opened by the default program on the user's system. If that happens to be your outlook with your account, then you see your mailbox. If I were to click your mailto link, it will open my Thunderbird with my account. This is, in fact, the only way this mechanic can work.
